# Change font based on language reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, i18next

I'm using reactjs, and I used `i18next` to change the language of my website, Now I need to assign different fonts to the different languages.

I'm defining the font in a css file.

How can I update that font depending on the language used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very familiar with `i18next`, but you can simply change the className of the div containing the text based on the language you are using.

```
//.jsx file

  <div className = {i18.language}>
    //some text goes here
  </div>

//css file
  .en{
    font-size:16px
   }
  .fr{
    font-size:12px
   }
//etc.
```